# Broken Urls calls found in access log

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been receiving broken url calls in the access log and it spikes CPU utilization and server load.

```
------------------------
[09/Jul/2016:14:50:27 +0530] "GET **/detailpage/news/science-technology/48** HTTP/1.1" 200 14477 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "1.39.62.232, 54.239.188.60"

[09/Jul/2016:14:50:27 +0530] "GET **/detailpage/news/science-techno** HTTP/1.1" 200 13082 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "1.39.62.232, 54.239.188.60"

[09/Jul/2016:14:50:27 +0530] "GET /**detailpage/news/science-technol** HTTP/1.1" 200 13090 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "1.39.62.232, 54.239.188.60"

[09/Jul/2016:14:50:27 +0530] "GET **/detailpage/news/sci** HTTP/1.1" 200 13073 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "1.39.62.232, 54.239.188.60"

[09/Jul/2016:14:50:27 +0530] "GET **/detailpage/news/science-techn** HTTP/1.1" 200 13088 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "1.39.62.232, 54.239.188.60"

[09/Jul/2016:14:50:27 +0530] "GET **/detailpage/news/sc** HTTP/1.1" 200 13077 "-" "Amazon CloudFront" "1.39.62.232, 54.239.188.91"

------------
```

This has been happening for a many days for different URL calls. I couldn't find out the reason.

Could anyone help me out with this and suggest a solution to prevent it from happening.

Comment: perhaps just hackers?

Comment: Any solution to prevent this.?

Comment: check fail2ban. It should be able to do the job.

Comment: since all the requests are coming from Cloudfront, implementing fail2ban will block all the requests of cloudfront.